# We need to hardcode arguments so all the user need to do is just needs to run the bat file to upgrade the license

Tags: windows, batch-file, hardcode

We have an updated license stored in the file 'style.mfx'. We want to send to user and have it silently replace the old file by that name. The File will always be in c:.
I've tried this demo with no luck. I want to hard code targetName and replacementFile in the batch file.

```
@echo off
set targetName=%~NX1
set replacementFile=%~F2
call :processFolder
goto :EOF

:processFolder
rem For each folder in this level
for /D %%a in (*) do (
rem Enter into it, process it and go back to original
cd %%a
if exist "%targetName%" (
copy "%replacementFile%" "%targetName%" /Y
)
call :processFolder
cd ..
)
exit /B
```

cmd line isn't even working! but I want the arguments in the batch file...

```
app teststyle.mfx c:\teststyle.mfx

c:\Users\Joseph\Desktop>replace.bat teststyle.mfx c:\teststyle.mfx

c:\Users\Joseph\Desktop>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you really sure you want to silently change license files on users' computers?

Comment: Yes. '''''''''.

Comment: When developing batch-files, especially with tricky bugs, remove the `@echo off`, then you can see it run every line of code, and scroll back through the buffer for clues about what went wrong.

Comment: This is joseph's

Comment: brother talking

Comment: I was able to fix

Comment: the program's problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:processFolder
rem For each folder in this level
for /D %%a in (*) do (
rem Enter into it, process it and go back to original
 pushd "%%a"
 if exist "%targetName%" (
 copy "%replacementFile%" "%targetName%" /Y
 popd
)
goto :eof
```

`pushd/popd` can be used to save-and-return.

reaching end-of-file will return from a `call`ed routine.